# HTML & ASPX Link Issue

Tags: asp.net, html, hyperlink

I've recentley moved my entire website from the root directory into a secure folder, but when I try to access it I now get a error: Runtime Error - Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Set it to off to view the error (only if it's on a staging, non-production server). Remove the custom error page to see what's going on. Try and re-create the error on your dev machine first. You also have the option of logging or emailing the error stack to yourself.

Instead of moving the entire site to a "secure folder", implement some form of authentication for the pages you wish to protect.

Comment: you could try looking in the `control panel->Administrative tools->event viewer->Application for the error if the display is not playing.